# How do I batch import multiple images as individual layers in Krita?

Tags: batch-processing, import, krita

I have already tried importing multiple images with File -> Import Animation Frames. I tried importing a single GIF image and it didn't extract the layers so I did it manually myself, then I went back and tried to import each extracted png frames and it still only imports 1 single frame. What am I doing wrong? Does Krita not have this basic feature?

Answer (score 2):

To import multiple images as individual layers in Krita (4.0) you can use `Layer > Import/Export > Import layer` and then in the file chooser dialog box, select multiple images and then press import.

For importing sequential frame use the Import Animation Frames, Also use the animation work-space to check your animation layers in Timeline.